# How do I force all WPF windows to be the same size

Tags: c#, wpf, window, dimensions

I have an application that has multiple windows. When I move from window to window, all other windows are hidden.

The problem I have is when I start in Window A, which is in its 'restored' state, (i.e. not maximised). Then I open Window B and maximise that. When I close Window B and go back to Window A, I want Window A to be in the same maximised state that I set Window B to.

Is there a handy way to do this, or do I have to have each window firing events when it's dimensions are changed so that the other windows can be notified and resize accordingly?

Comment: You could try to bind the window height and width to a common binding target using a two way binding

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at the `WindowState` property of the closing window and set it for the window about to show.

Possible values can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/system.windows.windowstate.aspx), but should simply be a case of:

```
window2.WindowState = window1.WindowState;
```

**OP Edit:**

This worked. This is the simple solution I built around this suggestion:

```
public static class WindowStateManager
{
    public static WindowState _state;
    private static double _height;
    private static double _width;
    private static double _left;
    private static double _top;

    public static void SetState(this Window window)
    {
        _state = window.WindowState;

        _height = window.Height;
        _width = window.Width;
        _left = window.Left;
        _top = window.Top;
    }

    public static void ApplyState(this Window window)
    {
        window.WindowState = _state;

        window.Height = _height;
        window.Width = _width;
        window.Left = _left;
        window.Top = _top;
    }

}
```

And for every window I'm interested in applying this to, I just add the following to the Constructor:

```
this.Activated += (s, a) => this.ApplyState();
this.LocationChanged += (s, a) => this.SetState();
```